# How to set Docker secret as an environment variable

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-secrets

Tried,

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  vector:
    image: custom
    command: -c /something.yaml
    environment:
      HTTP: 'URL'
      PWD_FILE: /run/secrets/my_external_secret
    configs:
      - something.yaml
    secrets:                    
     - my_external_secret
     - my_file_secret
    deploy:
      mode: replicated

configs:
  something.yaml:
    external: true
    name: bla1

secrets:                        
  my_external_secret:
    external: true
  my_file_secret:
    file: my_file_secret.txt
```

**In something.yaml:**

```
command: ["${PWD_FILE}"]  -------------> This prints as is... like /run/secrets/my_external_secret.
```

But how do i print the actual token value which is inside the secret.
Note: And i can see the container has the secret mounted inside my_external_secret,my_file_secret.

Comment: You will need to read the file containing the secret value.

Comment: @larsks you mean like cat /run/secrets/my_external_secret?

Comment: Something like that, yes. When you use docker secrets, the secret value is stored in a file. If you want to use that value for something, you need to read the value from the file.

Comment: If you are not obligated to use the secrets mechanism, you can simply enter just the variable name in the `environment` section (with empty value, like `PASSWORD:` ) and it will be passed on from the host.

Comment: @DannyB.. How can i do that with docker stack deploy command? any sample command?

Answer (score 1):

My approach involved this rather brutal shell script that enumerates all variables that end with `_FILE`, and reads the contents, creating a corresponding variable without the _FILE suffix :-

`secrets-entrypoint.sh`

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for var in $(env | cut -f1 -d"="); do
    if [[ $var =~ .*_FILE ]]
    then
        read -r ${var%_FILE} < ${!var}
    fi
done

exec $@
```

To use it, it needs to be injected in as the new entrypoint:

```yaml
configs:
  entrypoint:
    file: secrets-entrypoint.sh

services:
  vector:
    configs:
      - source: entrypoint
        target: ./usr/local/bin/secrets-entrypoint.sh
        mode: 0777
    entrypoint: ["secrets-entrypoint.sh","previous-entrypoint-if-any"]
    command: whatever
```

Written like this, it chains with any exiting entrypoint (if any) or just calls the command line after doing its work.
It probably does require `bash` and might need a bit of a massage to assume only /bin/sh level compatibility.

It will probably do stupid things if it encounters an image that uses variables that use _FILE as a suffix for other purposes. Checking for the existence of the file might be a necessary sanity check.

Comment: There's `file_env`, a [slightly more comprehensive function to do the same thing](https://medium.com/@adrian.gheorghe.dev/using-docker-secrets-in-your-environment-variables-7a0609659aab), floating around, which I think originates from MySQL.